# P:calendar PrimeFaces Data do Dia Anterior

Tags: primefaces

Alguem já teve problema com p:calendar retornando a data como sendo do dia anterior as 23h ?
Você seleciona a data e quando enviar ela captura como do dia Anterior as 23h.

Alguma solução?
Na View:

```
< p:calendar id="dataInicio" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="99/99/9999" size="15" maxlength="10" navigator="true" locale="pt" value="#{gerenciaNfeBean.filter.dataInicio}" effect="show">
< f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" locale="pt_BR" />
```

Model:

```
protected Date dataInicio;
```

Web.XML

```
< context-param>
< param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE
< param-value > true </ param-value >
    </ context-param>
```

Comment: No código se você usar um `new Date()` retorna correto ?

Comment: Retorna correto. O problema é somente se tentar usar o componente.

Comment: Vou tentar simular e te retorno. Você tentou sem os parâmetros adicionais? Sem o web.xml e o `f:converter`?

Comment: Realmente eu não me recordo, porque foram tantos teste que eu fiz que nem sei mais quais combinações eu tentei. 

Comment: Sugiro você fazer isso e ver o comportamento.